# Extracting value from a sublist from the Sales Order and storing it on Custom Body Field on Sales Order SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, sublist

I would like to create a suitescript that goes into the sales order's "salesteam" sublist and stores the first value from the sublist into a custom body field on the same sales order after saving the sales order. Below is my code. The custom field does has blank value.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/record'], function(record) {

  function afterSubmit(context) {

    // Retrieve the current record object
    var currentRecord = context.newRecord;

    // Retrieve the value from the sublist (in this example, we are using the first line of the 'salesteam' sublist)
    var sublistValue = currentRecord.getSublistValue({
      sublistId: 'salesteam',
      fieldId: 'employee',
      line: 0 // Replace 0 with the line number of the sublist item you want to retrieve the value from
    });

    // Set the value of a custom body field to the value retrieved from the sublist
    currentRecord.setValue({
      fieldId: 'custbody_salesrep_sublist',
      value: sublistValue
    });

  }

  return {
    afterSubmit: afterSubmit
  };

});
```

Comment: Hi @Ven - firstly, I have never extracted a value from the salesteam sublist, as I did not think it was possible. What value is returned when you make the "getSublistValue" call? Have you added a log.debug('val', sublistValue) line to check if any value is returned? May be worth testing if the line starts at 1, and not 0.

Comment: hello. I adjusted the code and made it work. it returns the first value (which is what I wanted to begin with).